# How to set baseUrl in Retrofit?

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I want to set the BaseUrl in Retrofit to change dynamically between stage and live because i have an app that has stage and live version. So i made a spinner and the user can select either he wants. But the problem is that after the user select the flavor he wants and then wants to change again it doens't work because the baseUrl is not changing like it should be.

I have this class where is defined the API_URL but it's not working :

```
@Singleton
class SingleUrlApi {
    companion object{
        public var API_URL_STAGE = BuildConfig.STAGE
    }
}
```

and then i have another function that uses this API_URL_STAGE

```
 override fun getUrl(shopUrl: ShopUrl, vararg args: String): String {
        return when (shopUrl) {
            ShopUrl.API_BASE -> if (SingleUrlApi.API_URL_STAGE) {
                context.localizedContext(localeManager.getCurrentLocale()).getString(R.string.base_url_stage)
            } else {
                context.localizedContext(localeManager.getCurrentLocale()).getString(R.string.base_url_live)
            }
            ShopUrl.WEB_BASE -> if (SingleUrlApi.API_URL_STAGE) {
                context.localizedContext(localeManager.getCurrentLocale()).getString(R.string.base_web_url_stage)
            } else {
                context.localizedContext(localeManager.getCurrentLocale()).getString(R.string.base_web_url_live)
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use OkHttp along with Retrofit.
Then, you can use an [OkHttpInterceptor](https://square.github.io/okhttp/interceptors/) to change the URL of the request

```
public final class HostSelectionInterceptor implements Interceptor {

  @Override public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request request = chain.request();
    String host = //logic to fetch the new URL
    if (host != null) {
      HttpUrl newUrl = request.url().newBuilder()
          .host(host)
          .build();
      request = request.newBuilder()
          .url(newUrl)
          .build();
    }
    return chain.proceed(request);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there another way to do it? because that way i would need to change all my apis

Comment: Retrofit is immutable. So there is no way to change the base URL on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

An easy and effective way is to use this library: [RetrofitUrlManager](https://github.com/JessYanCoding/RetrofitUrlManager)